# Lightroom: Reject a photo in compare view?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5, comparison

While comparing two photos in Lightroom 5, is there an easy way to reject one or the other?  When I hit the X key both are marked as rejected.  It is time consuming to make do the comparison using the arrows and then go back to grid view and figure out which is which.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Comparison view you have the "Select" image on the left and "Candidate" image on the right. By clicking on either image you will get a white border/line around the image.  It's only this image that the "X" key will act upon, not both.

If it's the "Select" image then it will be flagged as rejected, if its the "Candidate" image then it will be flagged as rejected.

Note flagging either image as rejected does not remove them from the Comparison view.

Also note to swap the white border from "select" to "candidate" use the "\" (backslash) key.

I am running Lightroom 5.6

Comment: To remove a rejected image from the comparison view as soon as you reject it, set the filter in the film strip down at the bottom to only show unmarked and picked images. Now as soon as an image gets rejected it gets filtered out and is no longer displayed (but it's **not** deleted or removed from the catalogue)